# How do we replace below 'x' sub string with 'y' sub string using regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I want to replace substring `src="/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg"` with substring `jira/rally/images` using regular expression in Java.

Below is the query to get the list of the String which contains substring `src="/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg"`

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("comment", "%<img%"));
criteria.setMaxResults(1);
List<Comments> list = criteria.list();
```

How can i replace using regex? Please help me here.

Let's say `xxxxxxxxsrc="/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpgxxxxxxxx` is the string then after the replacement I am expecting `xxxxxxxxsrc="jira/rally/images/Note.jpgxxxxxxxx`

the no. `63338424306` can be any random no.
image name & format 'Note.jpg' can be changed i.e. 'abc.png' etc.

Basically, I want to replace `/slm/attachment/63338424306/` with `jira/rally/images`

Thanks to all of you for your answers. I have updated the question little bit, please help me with that.

Comment: for `src="/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg` after the replacement what do you expect as output?

Comment: Let's say xxxxxxxxsrc="/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpgxxxxxxxx is the string then after the replacement i am expecting xxxxxxxxjira/rally/imagesxxxxxxxx & the no. 63338424306 can be any random no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a capturing group for the `src="` part and match the part that you want to replace.

```
(src\s*=\s*")/slm/attachment/\d+
```

- `(` Capture group

  - `src\s*=\s*"` Match `src`, 0+ whitespace chars, `=`, 0+ whitespace chars and `"`
- `)` Close group
- `/slm/attachment/` Match literally
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits

Note that if you want to match 0+ spaces only and no newlines, you could use a space only or `[ \t]*` to match a space and tab instead of `\s*`

In Java

```
String regex = "(src\\s*=\\s*\")/slm/attachment/\\d+";
```

And use the first capturing group in the replacement:

```
$1jira/rally/images
```

Result:

```
src="jira/rally/images/Note.jpg
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gq4xco/2) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Q9WYyb)

For example:

```
String string = "src  = \"/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("(src\\s*=\\s*\")/slm/attachment/\\d+", "$1jira/rally/images"));
// src  = "jira/rally/images/Note.jpg
```

Comment: Hey - Thanks for your answer. I need to change little bit here. in the string src="/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg, before & after '=' there can be no space or any no. of spaces. we have to ignore those spaces(let it be those spaces) and replace the '/slm/attachment/63338424306/' with 'jira/rally/images/' Please help me here.

Comment: @Ajay Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/Gq4xco/2 I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Now it is expected :) But what would be the Java code statement for that ? like  a.replaceAll("?","?")

Comment: @Ajay You can see the demo if you want https://ideone.com/Q9WYyb  `matcher.replaceAll("$1jira/rally/images");`

Comment: Can you please help me with a.replaceAll(x,y) as Allan has mentioned ? that would be more helpful for me :)

Comment: @Ajay I have added this example to the answer. `final String string = "src  = \"/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg";
  System.out.println(string.replaceAll("(src\\s*=\\s*\")/slm/attachment/\\d+",  "$1jira/rally/images"));`

Answer (score 2):

```
yourString.replaceAll("src=\"/slm/attachment", "src=\"/jira/rally/images");
```

Comment: Hey Pavel - Will it work if after the attachment in the substring, there can be any random no. xxxxxxxxxx/Note.jpg ?

Comment: Yes. The method only replaces occurences of the first argument in yourString. It does not remove anything.

Comment: Hey Pavel - Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following replacement sequences:

```
String a = "abc 123 src=\"/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg abc 132";
String b = "abc 123 src=\"/slm/attachment/61118424306/Note.jpg xyz";
String c = "123xxsrc=\"/slm/attachment/51238424306/Note.jpgxx324";
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("(?<=src=\")/slm/attachment/\\d+","jira/rally/images"));
System.out.println(b.replaceAll("(?<=src=\")/slm/attachment/\\d+","jira/rally/images"));
System.out.println(c.replaceAll("(?<=src=\")/slm/attachment/\\d+","jira/rally/images"));
```

**output:**

```
abc 123 src="jira/rally/images/Note.jpg abc 132
abc 123 src="jira/rally/images/Note.jpg xyz
123xxsrc="jira/rally/images/Note.jpgxx324
```

**regex demo:** https://regex101.com/r/ZtRg49/7/

Comment: Hey Allan - very much thanks for your help! I have updated the question little bit, please help me with that :)

Comment: @Ajay: I have edited my answer to your change in requirements, does it work as expected?

Comment: Hey Allan - I need to change little bit here i.e. in the string "abc 123 src="/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg abc 132", before & after '=' there can be zero or any no. of spaces. for ex. "abc 123 src   
 =  "/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg abc 132" or "abc 123 src    = 
 "/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg abc 132" then it should ignore those spaces and change remaining as earlier.

Comment: @Ajay: Ok I see that someone else already answered the question. Next time could you make clear requirements from the begining? Thanks! I have adapted my answer a couple of times. Also don't hesitate to upvote if you think that I have helped you. :)

Comment: Sorry for that. Your answer was also very helpful. I have upvoted :) Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ajay: Thanks ;)

Comment: I have one more question. How do we extract substrings 'slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg' & 'Note.jpg' from the string "abc 123 src = "/slm/attachment/63338424306/Note.jpg abc 132" in to string variables i.e. var1 & var2. Again, 63338424306 could be any no. & Note.jpg could be any thinng like abc.png or abc.jpg ? Please help me with that.